# Importing a type declared with Type::Library in the same file but a different package?

Tags: perl, type-tiny

Why doesn't the following code, [ripped directly from the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::Library), work?

```perl
package Types::Mine {
   use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
   use Type::Library -base;
   use Type::Tiny;

   my $NUM = "Type::Tiny"->new(
      name       => "Number",
      constraint => sub { looks_like_number($_) },
      message    => sub { "$_ ain't a number" },
   );

   __PACKAGE__->meta->add_type($NUM);

   __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}
```

When I try to `->import` it from the same file.

```perl
package main {
  use v5.30;
  BEGIN { Types::Mine->import( qw(Number) ) };
  die Number;
}
```

I'm getting,

```
Could not find sub 'Number' exported by Types::Mine at /tmp/test.pl line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp/test.pl line 20.
```

Shouldn't you be able to import a type library declared in the same file, though a different package, with

```perl
BEGIN { Types::Mine->import( qw(Number) ) };
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to either

1. Wrap the `package` in `BEGIN {}`, because remember if you're trying to write `use` in one package, the `require` and the `import` is in the `BEGIN {}` block too, ie these two are the same

   ```perl
   use Foo;
   BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import() }
   ```

   So you'll want to wrap the entire package in the `BEGIN {}` block, **AND** the `import` statement,

   ```perl
   BEGIN {
       package Types::Mine {
          use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
          use Type::Library -base;
          use Type::Tiny;

          my $NUM = "Type::Tiny"->new(
             name       => "Number",
             constraint => sub { looks_like_number($_) },
             message    => sub { "$_ ain't a number" },
          );

          __PACKAGE__->meta->add_type($NUM);

          __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Cheat, and put nothing in `BEGIN`, but [predeclare the sub.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70868805/124486)

   ```perl
   use v5.30;
   use sub Number;
   Types::Mine->import( qw(Number) );
   die Number;
   ```

   Note this method generates a warning for *"Overwriting existing sub"* in `Exporter::Tiny`, which can be silenced by instead doing,

   ```perl
   BEGIN { Types::Mine->import( { replace => 1 }, qw(Number) ) }
   ```

---

First option provided by `ilmari`.

Comment: You should be able to silence the warning using `Types::Mine->import( { replace => 1 }, qw(Number) )`